# Являются ли однокоренными слова "заказ" и "отказ"?

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Являются ли однокоренными слова *заказ* и *отказ*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ЗАКАЗАТЬ,  1. что. Поручить изготовить, исполнить, доставить что-л.

ОТКАЗАТЬ  1. (кому). Ответить отрицательно на просьбу, требование или какое-л. предложение.

Заказ/а/ть, отказ/а/ть - в современном языке эти слова имеют разные значения и не являются однокоренными, но при этом  в них можно выделить общий исторический корень КАЗ со значением являть, делать явным, видимым,  том числе говорить (озвучивать) что-либо. Разные значения слов определяют приставки.

Приставка ЗА указывает  указывает на достижение результата действия, состояния. Приставка ОТ указывает на  отстранение от кого-, чего-л.

Comment: Есть значение у ОТКАЗАТЬ = дать (часть чего-либо) кому-либо. Один заказывает, другой отказывает. Действия уравновешены процессом деньги — продукт, продукт — деньги. Схожие действия, корни слов не отличишь, так какой смысл называть их разными?